# Java file upload via ftp zero byte error

Tags: java, file-upload, ftp

I uploaded a file to server but the file empty.(size zero byte)

```
     int reply;
         ftp.connect(server,215);
         ftp.login(username, Password);
         System.out.println("Connected to " + server + ".");
         System.out.print(ftp.getReplyString());
         reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
         if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                ftp.disconnect();
                System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
         }
         System.out.println("FTP server connected.");
          ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
          ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

         InputStream input= new FileInputStream(source_file_path);

         ftp.storeFile(dest_dir, input);
         System.out.println(ftp.storeFile(dest_dir, input));
         System.out.println( ftp.getReplyString() );

                            input.close();

                            ftp.logout();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking in your code I think you are using Jakarta commons net.
If its true, try this:

```
ftp.connect(address, port);
boolean ft = ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
if(!ft)
    throw new Exception("Error");
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode(); or ftp.enterLocalActiveMode();
boolean log = ftp.login(user, password);
//if log == true, then u are logged in
ftp.storeFile(remote, local);
```

Also, if u want to use a progress bar to get te transfer progress u can try this method instead of ftp.storeFile

```
InputStream stO = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), ftp.getBufferSize());
OutputStream stD = ftp.storeFileStream(file.getName());

                    org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(
                    stO,
                    stD,
                    ftp.getBufferSize(),
                    file.length(),
                    new org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamAdapter() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void bytesTransferred(long totalBytesTransferred, int bytesTransferred,
                                long streamSize) 
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                pb.setMaximum((int)streamSize);
                                pb.setValue((int)totalBytesTransferred);
                            }
                            catch(Exception ex)
                            {
                                pb.setMaximum(-1);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    stO.close();
                    stD.close();
                    boolean ok = ftp.completePendingCommand();
                    if(!ok)
                        throw new Exception("ERROR while sending the file");
```

PS: pb is a JProgressBar

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the file twice.

```
ftp.storeFile(dest_dir, input);
System.out.println(ftp.storeFile(dest_dir, input));
```

As you're not reopening the input stream, the second time you are calling the `storeFile` method, the input stream is at EOF, so the file you're uploading the second time will have no content and hence overwrite the first file.

To print the result of `storeFile` you should:

```
Object result = ftp.storeFile(dest_dir, input);
System.out.println(result);
```